# HTML Object tag fallback content not displayed in case of failure

Tags: html

I have to display a PDF inside a modal dialog, for which I'm using the object element. As per my understanding, the moment I assign a URL to the "data" attribute of the object element, it'll make an internal call to the URL to fetch the document. What if that call fails due to, say, connectivity issues? I have a div (the error message container) inside the object tag as the fallback content, which is supposed to be displayed if the call fails. But that isn't happening. If the document is not being loaded, the dialog remains blank, instead of showing my error message. Below is the markup for the object element.

```
<object id="pdfContainer" type="application/pdf">
  <div id="pdfFetchFailureMessage" data-message-container="pdfFetchFailureMessage" class="spacer">
    <div class="message-group">
      <div class="messaging error customer-level" data-message-context="default">
        <div class="message-container" data-focus-first-message="" tabindex="-1">
          <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon"></i></span>
          <div class="message-content">
            <p role="error"><em class="visuallyhidden">error</em>The form could not be generated at the moment. Please try again later.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</object>
```

I'll be assigning the URL to the "data" attribute dynamically, which initiates the call. If the call fails, I should get the div with id **pdfFetchFailureMessage** in the dialog, but it's coming up blank. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Put the message-content div outside the object tag and use JS to check for the load event error.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? How do I handle the loading error? I don't think the onerror attribute works on an object element.

Answer (score 0):

Put the message-content div outside the object tag and use JS to check for the load event error and show your message.

```js
var pdf = document.querySelector('#pdfContainer');
var msg = document.querySelector('#pdfFetchFailureMessage');
pdf.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
  msg.classList.remove('hidden');
});
pdf.setAttribute('data', 'http://box2d.org/manual.pdf');
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object id="pdfContainer" type="application/pdf"></object>
    <div id="pdfFetchFailureMessage" data-message-container="pdfFetchFailureMessage" class="spacer hidden">
      <div class="message-group">
        <div class="messaging error customer-level" data-message-context="default">
          <div class="message-container" data-focus-first-message="" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon"></i></span>
            <div class="message-content">
              <p role="error"><em class="visuallyhidden">error</em>The form could not be generated at the moment. Please try again later.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```